# How Do I Setup Cross Domain Ajax Requesting/Receiving Using Nginx Reverse Proxy(VPS)?

Tags: ajax, nginx, apache2, reverse-proxy, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to properly set up an Nginx reverse proxy server(VPS) running on Linux Ubuntu 22.04. What I need to do is send an Ajax request cross-domain. What I am sending specifically is string data from a form that will be processed by the receiving server. My website is hosted by DreamHost(shared plan) and my reverse proxy and upstream servers are both VPSs with root/sudo access. I will post the code for my ajax request, nginx configuration, and a console error log. Thank you so much in advance for your time and help. I’ve spent already 2 days on this and it’s really confusing even when trying to compare it with similar issues…

Additional info:

-My website is coded with php

-Reverse proxy is Nginx

-Upstream server is Apache2

-Cloud flare proxy is off for all domains

Ajax/Jquery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#agree-cont-btn').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            // Serialize the form data
        var agreeDataGroup1 = $('.agreement-form,.agreement-form-2').serialize();
        var agreeDataGroup2 = $('.agreement-form,.agreement-form-2').serialize();
        console.log("Form Data:", agreeDataGroup1);
        console.log("Form Data:", agreeDataGroup2);

        // Make an AJAX request with 2 forms to processing page
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "https://receivingdomain.com/path/to/myfile.php",   //url to send form data
            data: agreeDataGroup1,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Response:",response);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Error:", error);
            }
        });
        //Sending same request to next page for printing and reviewing...
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "agreement.php",   //url to send form data
            data: agreeDataGroup2,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log("Response:",response);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Error:", error);
            }
        });

    });
});

</script>
```

Nginx reverse proxy server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name proxy.myproxy.com;
    root /var/www/html/proxy.myproxy.com;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name proxy.myproxy.com;
    root /var/www/html/proxy.myproxy.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxy.myproxy.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/proxy.myproxy.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://dev1.sendingdomain.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://dev1.sendingdomain.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://sendingdomain.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://sendingdomain.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'dev1.sendingdomain.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';

        proxy_pass http://receivingdomain.com;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Console log errors:

[Error] Origin "sending-domain-url" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load "receiving-domain-file-url" due to access control checks.

[Error] Failed to load resource: Origin "sending-domain-url" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Status code: 200 (myfile.php, line 0)

Note:urls all removed to allow posting

What I've tried:
I have tried going back and forth with chatgpt to get help on this issue. However, I just managed to get the configuration file created and server up and running. I have changed the access control allow origin domain many times and even ended up setting it to "*" for all domains just to see if that would even work. I even set up my apache2 config to allow all domains through too. Currently, I just have different variations set up of "sending domain" in my reverse proxy server file as you can see up top and by variations I mean I added in the main domain as well without the "dev1" even though the information is being sent from the "dev1" subdomain. I just added those in to test it out because I got tired of going back and forth changing the file.